# One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, .net, mariadb, asp.net-core-webapi

I received this error message when I tried to access from URL the ASP.NET Core Web API JSON data:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>
> Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
> System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
>
> at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints()
> at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
> at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
> at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
> at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
> at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
> at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader)
> at WebAPI.Controllers.VoltageController.Get(String date) in C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\WebAPI\WebAPI\Controllers\VoltageController.cs:line 37

In the 37 row I have this line of code:

```
using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
{
    mycon.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
    {
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        table.Load(myReader);

        myReader.Close();
        mycon.Close();
    }
}
```

37 row means:

```
table.Load(myReader);
```

When I call a procedure from heidi I see fields with null values.

[image: null values]

This is my full code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MySqlConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/voltage")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VoltageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public VoltageController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetData")]
        public JsonResult Get(string date)
        {
            string query = $"CALL Pivot_Auto_Last_Volt('{date}');";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AppCon");

            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                mycon.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader);

                    myReader.Close();
                    mycon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(table);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I get a solution to this problem?

Database is MariaDB version 10.11.5 ..